# Find urn of svf file to retrieve metadata

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I want to retrieve metadata/properties from a DWG stored in BIM360.
Assuming this [endpoint](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) can be used.

How can I get the urn of the DWG for this API call?

[https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/%7Burn%7D/metadata)

Does the [DM API](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/) provide that information?
Or do I have to translate the DWG into SVF myself in my own bucket?

The viewer can show the DWG very quickly, so I think the SVF is stored anywhere.
When loaded into the viewer I could use the viewer method [getBulkProperties()](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Model/#getbulkproperties-dbids-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback), but I want to retrieve metadata without viewing the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to retrieve your file in BIM360. You can follow this tutorial [Download file](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/) until step 5 (btw if you want the latest version of your file you can use [Get tip](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-tip-GET/) instead of [Get versions](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-versions-GET/).

Into `relationships`, you should get something like that :

```
"derivatives": {
    "data": {
        "type": "derivatives",
        "id": "dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwc3RnOmZzLmZpbGU6dmYuNmJWcjRFVkRTYU9weWtjemVRWVIyUT92ZXJzaW9uPTE"
    }, ...
```

`id` is your file **urn**.

Now you can follow this tutorial [Extract metadata](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/xtract-metadata/task4-extract_metadata/) to get metadata and properties.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@AlexAR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9365707/alexar)'s answer, you can also take a look at the [Hubs Browser](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/) tutorial which explains the process of drilling down into your BIM360 folder structure and finding the URN of whatever document you're interested in.